# Создание защищенного вебсокет-сервера на Java

Tags: java, websocket, ssl

Можно ли создать сервер вебсокетов для wss протокола (с использованием SSL) для библиотеки Tyrus? В документации есть только пример создания такого клиента.

Answer (score 1):

вот тут https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket есть всё что нужно, проверено.